# WSO2 api manager change DB to oracle cuase "DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 api manager 3.2.0 throws exception while start server that changed DB config to oracle and add driver in lib folder.

Exceptions :

org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234

```
[2021-06-20 21:32:12,853] ERROR - DefaultRealm nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:871) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8617) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:316) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1058) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:851) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8617) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:316) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:271) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1058) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:851) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8617) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:316) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
[2021-06-20 21:32:12,884] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:286) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61) [org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:871) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8617) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:316) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1058) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:851) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8617) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:316) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:271) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1058) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:851) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8617) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:316) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: You should pass the apim version too. But in this case try to follow `TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`  Seems the jdbc url and the ORA service name don't match

Comment: Really thanks, version is 3.2.0. just a question,  I should excute scripts in oracle db or no wso2 by it selft run it? -@gusto2

Comment: You need to initialize the db separately. We advice to post follow-up questions separately

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064493/wso2-api-manager-30-2-0-change-db-to-oracle-not-working @gusto2

Comment: Please check your DB connection details provided in the deployment.toml file under [database.shared_db]. Also, check whether the DB is up and running properly/ not idle for a long time, along with the connectivity check between APIM and the relevant DB.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I changed region from persian to united stated and it fixed. beacuse Iran is under sanctions.