# WSO2 api manager 30.2.0 change db to oracle not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 api manager 3.2.0 change db to oracle not working.

I excuted script in oracle and

I copied oracle jdbc8 jar in lib folder and

deployments.toml config as following :

```
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.shared_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.64.3:1521/TEST_PDB"
username = "shared_db"
password = "shared_db"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"

[database.apim_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.64.3:1521/TEST_PDB"
username = "apim_db"
password = "apim_db"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```

exception :

```
ERROR - DefaultRealm nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: can you please add the whole error stack? did you try connecting to dbs using a dbclient and check whether the tables are created properly?

Answer (score 0):

Is the db reachable?

Have you tried connecting to the db using a client?